.NET Return Type for CameraCharacteristics.Get(ControlAeAvailableTargetFpsRanges)
I am using Camera2 in a .NET Xamarin project.  I would like to control the FPS camera settings.  To do this I am using
 CameraCharacteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.ControlAeAvailableTargetFpsRanges);

This should be the equivalent of the following Java code:
 cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES);

Which returns an array of integer ranges:
Range<Integer>[] ranges 

I cannot figure out what the equivalent return value is for the .NET api.  It returns a Java.Object?  but I need to know the specific type.  I can't seem to find any documentation on this.  I've tried casting to Android.Util.Range[] and Android.Hardware.Camera2.CameraCharacteristics.Key? as per the Microsoft docs, but this results in a runtime error about the cast.
Anyone have insight as to the .NET equivalent return value is for this API?
Thanks.
